# java - SQL generated keys

Tags: java, sql

В общем, проблема в том что при SQL запросе на update записи не возвращаются generated keys, хотя запись обновляется, с insert все работает корректно, а вот с update все ломается, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой.

UPDATE метод rs.next() всегда возвращает false

`int user_id = 0;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(User.UPDATE_USER, new String[]{User.ID});
            preparedStatement.setString(1, password);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, username);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            rs = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (rs.next()) {
                user_id = rs.getInt(1);
            }
        } finally {
            if (rs != null)
                rs.close();
            preparedStatement.close();
            dbConnection.close();
        }`

Сам sql код

```
static final String UPDATE_USER = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME
        + " SET " + PASSWORD + " = ?"
        + " WHERE "+ USERNAME +" = ?;";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Согласно документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])):

> Creates a default PreparedStatement object capable of returning the auto-generated keys designated by the given array. This array contains the names of the columns in the target table that contain the auto-generated keys that should be returned. **The driver will ignore the array if the SQL statement is not an INSERT statement, or an SQL statement able to return auto-generated keys** (the list of such statements is vendor-specific).

То есть, драйвер проигнорирует список автогенерированных ключей, если запрос не является `INSERT` операцией

Comment: То есть если я хочу узнать id обновленной записи мне обязательно нужно после этого делать SELECT? По другому никак?

Comment: В **Oracle** и **Postgreql** есть ключевое слово `RETURNING`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html В **MySQL** придется делать `SELECT`

Comment: спасибо, понял, а то на некоторых сайтов при update так же использовали generatedkeys, но теперь все встало на свои места.